# Accumulation points of the graph of a function

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Consider $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ and its graph $\{(x,f(x))|x\in\mathbb{R}\} \subset\mathbb{R}^2$. Does the graph have a countable number of accumulation points $(x_i, f(x_i))$ (among the possibly uncountable such points) such that the collection of the $x_i$'s are dense in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Presumably you mean ether "that the collection of the $x_i$ is dense in $\mathbb R$" or "that the $x_i$ are dense in $\mathbb R$"? Also, are you asking whether there exists a countable set of accumulation points of the graph with this property, or are you asking whether the set of *all* accumulation points of the graph is countable and has this property?

Comment: @joriki edited to clarify that there could be uncountably many accumulation points, but the question is asking if a countable subset has the property mentioned.

Comment: The lack of singular/plural congruence in the last sentence still creates unclarity -- did you mean one of the two formulations that I suggested?

Comment: I think countability is a red herring. Let me rephrase: Call $x\in\mathbb{R}$ *tame* (for $f$) if $(x,f(x))$ is an accumulation point of the graph of $f$. Then the question is whether there is a countable dense set of tame points in $\mathbb{R}$. But any dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$ has a countable dense subset, so the only question remaining is whether the set of tame points is dense. In fact, if not, there is an open interval with no tame points in it, so you really only need to ask if a tame point must exist at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(**Edited** to fix a serious – and elementary – mistake.) Let $G$ be any discrete subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then $G$ is countable. To see this, consider the open disk centered at each point of $G$ with radius $r/2$, where $r$ is the infimum of distances to the other points of $G$. These disks are mutually disjoint, and so their number must be countable because each contains points with rational coordinates.

Therefore, every nonempty open interval $I$ contains some $x$ so that $G\cap(x\times\Bbb{R})=\emptyset$.

Now let $G$ be the graph of the function $f$. By the above result, $G$ cannot be discrete, so it contains at least one accumulation point.

To see that the set $A$ of $x$, so that $(x,f(x))$ is an accumulation point of $G$, is itself dense, let $I$ be a nonempty open interval apply the above result to the function $f\circ\phi$, where $\phi\colon\Bbb{R}\to I$ is a homeomorphism.

Finally, any dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$ contains a countable dense subset. Applying this to $A$ finishes the argument.

Comment: Do you mean a closed discreet subset G? because every discreet subset of a compact set in $\Bbb R^2$  need not be finite.

Comment: @rohit: Discrete subsets are automatically closed. What is your definition of discrete? Mine is that each singleton set is open (in the subset topology).

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Good grief – you're right, of course. What's wrong with my head today!? (I shall fix the answer soon.)

Comment: @rohit: You're right, as Brian pointe out above. I must have had an attack of the stupid bug – usually I know these things perfectly well.

Answer (score 1):

Let $I$ be a non-empty open interval in $\Bbb R$, and let $G_I=\left\{\langle x,f(x)\rangle:x\in I\right\}$ be the graph of $f\upharpoonright I$. Let $\mathscr{B}$ be a countable base for the Euclidean topology on $\Bbb R^2$, let $$\mathscr{B}_0=\{B\in\mathscr{B}:B\cap G_I\text{ is countable}\}\;,\tag{1}$$ and let $H_I=G_I\setminus\bigcup\mathscr{B}_0$. $\mathscr{B}_0$ is countable, and $B\cap G_I$ is countable for each $B\in\mathscr{B}_0$, so $G\cap\bigcup\mathscr{B}_0$ is countable, and $|H_I|=|G_I|=|\Bbb R|$. Suppose that $p\in H_I$, and $p\in B\in\mathscr{B}$; clearly $B\notin\mathscr{B}_0$, so $B\cap G_I$ is uncountable, and therefore $B\cap H_I$ is uncountable. Thus, every point of $H_I$ is not just an accumulation point of $H_I$: if $p\in H_I$, every open nbhd of $p$ meets $H_I$ (and hence $G_I$) in an uncountable set.

Now let $\mathscr{I}$ be the collection of open intervals in $\Bbb R$ with rational endpoints, and for each $I\in\mathscr{I}$ choose $x_I\in I$ such that $\langle x_I,f(x_I)\rangle$ is an accumulation point of $H_I$ and hence of $G_I$; clearly $\{x_I:I\in\mathscr{I}\}$ is a countable dense subset of $\Bbb R$, and $\langle x_I,f(x_I)\rangle$ is an accumulation point of the graph of $f$ for each $I\in\mathscr{I}$.

Comment: I never noticed that you had answered this two hours prior to fixing up my own answer in response to your comment. (Following the link on the inbox takes you direct to the comment, of course, so it can be tricky to notice new content on the page if you don't scroll to look for it.) If I had noticed, perhaps I would have deleted my answer instead of fixing it. But now that I have noticed, I think I'll leave it up anyway, since it may be different enough from yours to warrant interest. At least, I'm upvoting yours.

Comment: @Harald: I like having them both up; both contain ideas that are useful more generally. (And I’ve also upvoted yours; I forgot before.)